# Annoying terminal bug, is this known and a solution is out there?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan

I use the default terminal.app
I use cmd+d command to split panes so I can look at the part of the code while using another command.

This annoying bug comes up when de-splitting the panes.
What it does is that it basically reduces the vertical length of the terminal, so that after de-split, terminal is not filling my screen vertically.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any true solution is going to have to depend on a bug fix. But this works for me:

- Set the window default size in Preferences/Profiles/Window.
- Assign a shortcut key to Window/Return to Default Size.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the inspector that you get with Shell -> Show Inspector.